# Can I control a variable from one batch file with another?

Tags: variables, batch-file

I'm using two batch files, and I need to control variables in one of them, from the other. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you start both batch files in different windows, or parallel in one window, are their running both at the same time? If you could show samples, it could be solved (maybe).

Comment: Is this for Windows or some other OS?

Comment: @Patrick: Batch files usually refer to Windows. Unless you can show me a Unix user that calls their shell scripts »batch files«, too.

Comment: @jeb: Any helpful hints as to what madness I have done wrong in my answer? ;)

Comment: @Joey: Why do you think your answer could be wrong? Ok, it could be a solution for an other question, but we can't know this.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly influence one process' environment from another process. You know, we've kinda outgrown ye olde days of real mode by now :-)

This all depends a bit on what you're trying to achieve here. If you're calling one batch file from the other, as in

```
call second.cmd
```

then the called one »inherits« the environment of the parent batch. So any variable you defined earlier will continue to exist in the child batch. You cannot propagate changes up to the parent, though and you cannot change a variable in the child batch after it has been started, too. It might still be a viable option if all you need is to perform some one-time initialization before starting the child batch.

What you could do is to agree on a file used by both batch files that they will use as a means of communicating with each other, likely located in the temporary directory. Each batch file would need to regularly check for the file to be present and if so, read it and update its variables accordingly. For that to succeed you need points in the batch files where they *can* look for that file. The simplest would be two files that simply do a bit communication with each other:

[image]

The code for that is here:

**callchat.cmd:**

```
@echo off
set SENDFILE=%TEMP%\1.out
set RCVFILE=%TEMP%\1.in
start call chat.cmd
ping -w 5000 -n 1 123.45.67.89 >nul 2>&1
set RCVFILE=%TEMP%\1.out
set SENDFILE=%TEMP%\1.in
start call chat.cmd
```

**chat.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem Prevent direct use 
if not defined SENDFILE goto :eof
if not defined RCVFILE goto :eof

set MESSAGE0=I don't know what to say ...
set MESSAGE1=Foo
set MESSAGE2=Bar
set MESSAGE3=Hey there!
set MESSAGE4=Meow.

:loop
  rem wait a bit
  ping -n 1 -w 1000 123.45.67.89 >nul 2>&1
  rem look whether we need to show something
  if exist %RCVFILE% (
    for /f "delims=" %%l in (%RCVFILE%) do echo Received message at %TIME% - %%l
    del "%RCVFILE%"
  )
  rem randomly send out messages. Roughly ever three times we try this
  set /a msg=%random% %% 5
  set msg=!MESSAGE%msg%!
  if %RANDOM% LSS 10000 (
    >>%SENDFILE% echo(%msg%
    echo(Sent message "%msg%"
  )
goto loop
```

The batch file is started twice, with different input/output files – in fact, the reversed role of the files from the first invocation. Then it's little more than an endless loop that looks into its input file and read what's in there and writing stuff to its output file (which is the input file for the other batch).

I had to introduce a delay in starting both of them to avoid the PRNGs for both being exactly the same. It also reduced the cases where access to the file failed (this could probably be alleviated by renaming it before reading from it – or, if writing longer content, renaming it to its final name only after being done writing). It's just a simple demo application to show you that it might be possible that way.

To set environment variables you wouldn't print out what's in the file but call it as a batch file, for example:

```
if exist %RCVFILE% call %RCVFILE%
```

It would need the proper extension for that, though. You can also read it line by line and have each line contain a `VARIABLE=VALUE` pair:

```
if exist %RCVFILE% call for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in (%RCVFILE%) do set %%a=%%b
```

The techniques mentioned above for improving reliability when accessing the same file from two different programs still apply.

As mentioned, this is only a rough idea how you could operate, *iff* I understood your question correctly.

Comment: +1, I think it solves this sort of problems nearly in a perfect way, but one problem is still there, is this the concrete problem of the OP?

Comment: @jeb: That is what I don't know. It's more guessing. But this here is something I wanted to implement for some time now anyway.